# Questions about visiting unrecognized states are acceptable? Most of them inevitably lead to law infringement

Tags: discussion

I searched all the Meta but it seems the issue hadn't been discussed thoroughly yet.

Let me start with an example. Here are two questions presented on Travel SE:

[What is the correct way of visiting Abkhazia without violating Georgian laws?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69307/42757)

[Can I travel to Abkhazia on a Russian visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91118/can-i-travel-to-abkhazia-on-a-russian-visa)

Compare those two questions and feel the difference.

The first one is asked with all the respect to laws and asker feels like seeking help to do it right, whilst the second one is asked provocatively with the clear intent to break the law, as every person can google in 5 seconds that Abkhazia is an unrecognized country occupied by Russian so visiting it by Russian visa is certainly a law infringement.

Should we allow such questions? I inspected [this](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/should-we-be-encouraging-others-to-break-the-law), [this](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated), [this](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/are-questions-about-controversial-practices-allowed) and [this](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/should-smuggling-questions-be-considered-on-topic) discussions but I feel they don't cover this issue properly. Visiting the unrecognized (in most cases occupied) territory is not like breaking outdated, fuzzy, frequently broken law or like breach that cannot be avoided [like in the answer from Thorsten](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3448/42757). It is not like crossing the street on red light or [smuggling two Iphones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/how-many-iphone-6-devices-can-i-bring-into-india?rq=1) or wearing fish-skeleton T-Shirt in Germany.

It **is** a fundamental international law infringement that directly corresponds with the topic of this site: advice on crossing country border in a correct, safe and confident way, I suppose, was one of the main purposes of this site.

Should we allow them and how to correctly handle these questions?

I saw many similar questions about visiting Crimea, Northern Cyprus, Kosovo and other lands, but ethical moments of such questions had been never discussed.

Comment: Would such a prohibition affect questions about visiting Taiwan or mainland China?

Comment: Let the community decide this, I just felt the necessity to raise this question for discussion

Answer (score 1):

## Is there a way?

Sure, **if it's legal**. Russian diplomats can probably visit those zones without any issues.

I don't think we should have questions like "How to get smuggled from Mexico to the USA".

But I think the questions about Syria have already been discussed, like how one can get duplicate passports and use one in Syria and the other in the USA. Should these questions and answers be allowed?

Comment: I didn't ask question "is there a way?" and dunno to what part of my question it corresponds. Your answer should probably be a comment. Russian diplomats is not really an argument as they do many things that has nothing to do with law